# add fade in/out jQuery hover addclass/remove

Tags: jquery, show, fade, onhover

I have a list of menu items generated dynamically (wordpess menu). I have the code set up now that depending on which menu item is hovered over, it adds a css class "Proj1, proj2, etc" to an image box ".show". the Proj1 Proj2 classes each have a different background image so effectively the image box switches the image depending on which menu item is hovered over. All good there.

What I can't seem to do is find a way to make the images fade in and out when being switched.

***I've been pulling my hair out for weeks, please help me Obi-Wan Kenobi***

```
var image=["proj1","proj2","proj3","proj4","proj5","proj6","proj7","proj8","proj9","proj10","proj11","proj13","proj14","proj15","proj16","proj17","proj18","proj19","proj20","proj21","proj22","proj23","proj24","proj25","proj26","proj27","proj28","proj29","proj30","proj31","proj32" ];

$(".list-group li").hover(function(){
  var value=  $(this).index();
  hoverContent(value);
});
function hoverContent(value){
    $("#list-content div").removeClass('show');
    $("#list-content div:nth-child("+value+")").addClass("show");
    $("#bg").removeClass().fadeOut();
    $("#bg").addClass(image[value]).fadeIn();
}
```

html is using wordpress php

```
    <div id="bg" class="content">
        <div id="list-content">
           <div class="show"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="menuItems">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li><a href="www.link.html">Menu Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.link.html">Menu Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.link.html">Menu Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.link.html">Menu Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="www.link.html">Menu Item 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. We really need to see your (**minimal**) HTML to be able to help.  Please visit the help centre and read how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok, added, thanks for the heads up

Comment: You might want to show the rendered HTML instead of the PHP.

Comment: We still can't see the HTML that this problem relates to.  PHP isn't relevant here, we need the rendered HTML.

Comment: I've added the rendered HTML, is there anything else I can provide that would help?

Comment: Have a look at this approach: https://jsfiddle.net/n62bqpym

Comment: @Shikkediel you're a genius, this worked, thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use the callback on `fadeOut` to execute changes when they finish their animations.

You can also avoid looking up array indices by storing extra information on your `<li>` elements in `data-*` attributes

```html
<li data-proj="proj1"> <!--  note the data attribute and value -->
  <a href="http://www.link.html">Menu Item 1</a>
</li>
```

```js
$(".list-group li").hover(function() {
  const li = $(this)
  const proj = li.data("proj")
  const index = li.index()

  $("#list-content div")
    .removeClass("show")
    .eq(index).addClass("show")

  $("#bg").fadeOut("fast", function() {
    $(this).removeClass().addClass(proj).fadeIn()
  })
}
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, when hovering over li nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

@Shikkediel wrote an elegant solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/n62bqpym

```
var image = ['proj1', 'proj2', 'proj3', 'proj4', 'proj5'];

$('.list-group li').hover(function() {
  hoverContent($(this).index());
});

function hoverContent(value) {
  $('#list-content div').removeClass('show').eq(value).addClass('show');
  $('#bg').attr('class', image[value]);
}
```